# Default belongs_to association value

Tags: associations, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, changeset

Job Model

```
schema "jobs" do
  belongs_to :status, Test.JobStatus,
    foreign_key: :status_id,
    references: :id,
    type: :string
  timestamps()
end
```

and I have a status Model as:

```
@primary_key {:id, :string, autogenerate: false}
schema "job_statuses" do
  field :title, :string
  field :description, :string
end
```

When I am inserting the job I need to put default job status(if its not in params). I know about defaults in belongs_to association but this thing is for perhaps to assign default values when you are assiging a relationship. Can any one point me how I can put default status for any newly created job(assumed job status id is "**acitve**" and its already in the database ) . sample is already here https://github.com/tanweerdev/jobs

> After cloning the project, just do this

```
Interactive Elixir (1.5.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> Test.Jobs.create_job_status()
iex(2)> Test.Jobs.test_default_status()
```

> (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 23502 (not_null_violation): null value in
>   column "status_id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: Note: if I add default value in the migration, there is no error while inserting and status is assoicated successfully but the changeset object which I am returning to user is not aware of the change and it returns null `status_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the default in the migration and define the association field to be `read_after_writes: true`. This will ensure that after inserting the record, that field will be read back from the database which will fix the problem you mentioned in your comment that the field was still `nil` after inserting the record successfully.

```
belongs_to :status, Test.JobStatus,
  foreign_key: :status_id,
  references: :id,
  type: :string,
  define_field: false

field :status_id, :integer, read_after_writes: true
```

Check out the documentation for more details about `define_field` [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#belongs_to/3-options) and `read_after_writes` [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#field/3-options).

Answer (score -1):

The most appropriate place to put a status creation would be inside your `Job.changeset/2` callback:

```
  @doc false
  def changeset(%Job{} = job, attrs) do
    job
    |> cast(attrs, @fields)
    |> validate_required(...)
    |> create_and_put_default_status() # ⇐ HERE
    |> ...
  end
```

Where the implementation of `create_and_put_default_status()` would conform the following spec:

```
@spec create_and_put_default_status(Plug.Conn.t) :: Plug.Conn.t
```